# In PySpark, why does the add_months function only work when given an integer, and not a Column of integers?

Tags: pyspark

I'm experimenting with PySpark, and the following has me stumped. The [documentation for the add_months function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.add_months.html) says it can take a Column as its second argument, but my simple toy examples are failing. Is this an error? Or am I missing some fundamental understanding of how to read the docs and/or the source code?

To recreate, start with a simple DataFrame containing a column of dates as strings:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

dates = ["2020-01-01", "2020-02-01"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(zip(dates), ["date"])
df.show()
```

Result:

```
+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2020-01-01|
|2020-02-01|
+----------+
```

The following code works. It adds 1 month. Note that I am passing an integer for the second argument.

```py
df.withColumn(
    "date_plus_one",
    F.add_months(
        F.col("date"),
        1,
    )
).show()
```

Result:

```
+----------+-------------+
|      date|date_plus_one|
+----------+-------------+
|2020-01-01|   2020-02-01|
|2020-02-01|   2020-03-01|
+----------+-------------+
```

However, this version does not work. Note that I am passing in a literal column of integer.

```py
df.withColumn(
    "date_plus_one",
    F.add_months(
        F.col("date"),
        F.lit(1)  # <-- only difference
    )
).show()
```

The error I receive is: "Column is not iterable."

According to the [documentation for add_months](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.add_months.html), the second argument should be able to receive either a *ColumnOrName*, or an int.

In fact, the [source code](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#add_months) will even convert an integer into a column of integers before passing along to the next function:

```py
def add_months(start: "ColumnOrName", months: Union["ColumnOrName", int]) -> Column:
    months = lit(months) if isinstance(months, int) else months
    return _invoke_function_over_columns("add_months", start, months)
```

Though, this is where my ability to read the source code stops.

I'm confused why my second attempt results in an error (because the function should be able to receive a column), and particularly the error, "Column is not iterable." *(I understand that Columns in PySpark are generally not iterable because they are spread across multiple RDDs, which is why I'm not supposed to write code myself to do things when a pyspark function exists to do it for me, like in this case.)*

Note that I'm getting similar errors for similar functions, like [date_sub()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_sub.html).

I would like to understand why the function doesn't seem to take the arguments that its signature says it can take.

Comment: while the doc states we "can" pass a column, if you sift through the spark package files to find the function, you'll see it is strongly typed and asks for an integer. specifically look for the `functions.py` file within the package which will be like `/<user loc>/spark-<version>/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious to understand the discrepancy when I first stumbled upon this. Turns out the documentation I/we usually refer is for the latest version!

So, I went through the spark package to find the source code for the version I was using (3.1.3) and, *voila!* The package used the older version of the function which is strongly typed and asks for an integer as an second input. An easy way to bypass it was to use the SQL expression within `expr` which readily accepts columns.

A little bit of research made things more clear (which, ideally, IMO should've been highlighted in the documentation itself). I read through the blames/commits on spark's github repo and found [this commit](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/899dec2ea36bcd934f1512b26e7fc8903e9f5ba8), tagged to [this jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-37738), which updated the function signatures for all date calculation functions. These updated versions have been rolled out with the **spark 3.3** version, meaning all previous versions will have the older version of the aforementioned functions and will continue to accept only integers.

---

Here's how you can find out about your version's functions.

When you run the function with a bad input, it'll raise an exception. The traceback will have the location to your `functions.py` file at the top.

Here's what mine looks like (in google colab)

[image: add_months error snapshot]

You can then follow the path, and search for the function's source which, in my case, was the following

```py
def add_months(start, months):
    """
    Returns the date that is `months` months after `start`

    .. versionadded:: 1.5.0

    Examples
    --------
    >>> df = spark.createDataFrame([('2015-04-08',)], ['dt'])
    >>> df.select(add_months(df.dt, 1).alias('next_month')).collect()
    [Row(next_month=datetime.date(2015, 5, 8))]
    """
    sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
    return Column(sc._jvm.functions.add_months(_to_java_column(start), months))
```

The aforementioned assumes the second input will always be an integer.

Comment: Thank you! Good to know I wasn't fundamentally mis-reading the documentation. I was beginning to doubt my ability. I'm running this on a cluster which I don't have control over, and it turns out the cluster has Spark 3.2.1, so yes, I was looking at the latest documentation (3.3.1). I will say it is very frustrating that the latest documentation doesn't mention an updated function signature. It only says, "New in version 1.5.0." which, to me, implies it hasn't changed since then. At least now I know to update my bookmarks to the version that matches the one installed on my cluster. Thanks!